# Tricky add,removeClass

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I'm facing some tricky challange with an acordition menu.I have a colorpicker from who i pick colors.Everything is ok until now.My colorpicker creates a cookie that retain the color user chosed. I also have panels how expands and colapse.The tricky point is that once i chose a color i can't expand,collapse my slides like before.

[Take a look](http://jsfiddle.net/Code_me/Y6Rrn/2/)

```
//This is the tricky part
$(".js_slide").click(function () {
    var $contentBlock = $(this).next("li[id^=content_]");

    if ($contentBlock.hasClass("is_open")) {
        $contentBlock.animate({
            width: '0%'
        }).removeClass("is_open");
    } 
    else {
        // if a content box is open (=> an element with the class .is_open exists), close it
        $(".js_content.is_open").animate({
            width: '0%'
        }).removeClass("is_open");
        $contentBlock.animate({
            width: '42%'
        }, 500).addClass("is_open");
    }
});
```

Comment: Just an FYI, there are quite a few `<li>` tags that you haven't closed in your jsFiddle example.

Comment: Done! but the problem isn't that :)

Comment: Ok I thought it was the .removeClass(), but your code bugs on all ends so I couldn't really answer it sorry :(

Comment: Something goes wrong after i change the colors for my acordition menu,thank's anyway.If you know someone who can fix it i'll be verry grateful :)